# Substring IN mysql need to fetch the word

Tags: mysql, sql

Table *[tbl_post]* has the *id, description[long_text]*.

The *description* field has the following values:

```
Hi how r u? #TravelingtheWorld #TravelingtheWorld
Hi how r u? #Traveled
bla bla bla travelbybus blah blah
blah blah blah @travelegency blah blah
the intelligence demonstrated in during tests iterations
blah blah blah testing blahh
blah blah blah tested blahh
```

We have **@** and **#** features.

If I try to search the value "test", I need the response of "test/tested/testing"

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(
            '$ipstring',
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(LOWER('description'), LOWER('$ipstring'), -1)
       ) , ' ',1 ) AS 'mystring'
FROM   tbl_post
WHERE `description` LIKE '$ipstring%'
   OR `description` LIKE '% $ipstring%'
   OR `description` LIKE '%#$ipstring%'
   OR `description` LIKE '%@$ipstring%'
```

1. Input search string

   ```
   $ipstring = "travel"
   ```

   Here I am getting output

   - Traveled
   - TravelingtheWorld
   - travelbybus
   - travelegency
2. Input search string

   ```
   $ipstring = "te"
   ```

   Here am getting output

   - terations  >>> Here i need "tests"(the intelligence demonstrated in during tests iterations)
   - testing
   - tested

Queries:

1. First query

   ```
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX ( CONCAT(
               'travel',
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(LOWER('Hi how r u? *TravelingtheWorld *TravelingtheWorld'), LOWER('travel'), -1 ) 
            ) , ' ',1 ) AS 'mystring'
   ```
2. Second query

   ```
   SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX ( CONCAT(
               'te',
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(LOWER('the intelligence demonstrated in during tests iterations'), LOWER('te'), -1 )
          ) , ' ',1 ) AS 'mystring'
   ```

If I add a space " " before input string " te", I will get "tests"

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX ( CONCAT(
               'te',
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(LOWER('the intelligence demonstrated in during tests iterations'), LOWER(' te'), -1 )
           ) , ' ',1 ) AS 'mystring'
```

But for first query : If I add a space " " before input string ' traveling'

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX ( CONCAT(
               'travel',
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(LOWER('Hi how r u? *TravelingtheWorld *TravelingtheWorld'), LOWER(' travel'), -1 )
           ) , ' ',1 ) AS 'mystring'
```

... I am not getting "TravelingtheWorld"

Comment: I see `$ipstring`: do you use PHP? If so, would a PHP solution suit you?

Comment: Yes we are using php Mysql But we need output in a single query mysql not in php. Thanks in advance

Comment: Even not if you would have a PHP function that would take as argument a query result set and would modify it and return it again? In pure MySql this is going to be monstrous code and I fear even less efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this query:

```
select *
from   (
        select description,
               substring_index(
                 substr(
                   description, 
                   instr(
                     concat(
                       ' ', 
                       replace(
                         replace(lower(description), '@', ' '), 
                         '#', 
                         ' '
                       ), 
                       ' '
                     ), 
                     ' travel'
                   )
                 ), 
                 ' ', 
                 1
               ) as extract
        from   tbl_post
       ) as m
where  length(m.extract) > 0
```

You would have to provide the search word like `' te'` or `' travel'` with prefixed space.

Comment: @pradeepandrewson2, did this solve your issue? Could you give some feed-back?